# How to add the screenshot at the end of the every scenario in the cucumber report

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, selenium-extent-report

I am able to take the screenshot and the report is stored in the local(project dir) folder.
I want to display the screenshot in the cucumber report.

WebDriver Library

```
@Configuration
public class WebDriverLibrary {
    @Value("${remote.url}")
    private URL remoteUrl;


    @Value("${browser}")
    private String browser;

    @Bean
    public WebDriver getChromeDriver(){
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        return new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    }
```

Page Scope:

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PageScope {
}
```

Feature file

```
Feature: Signup Feature
  This feature will deal with Signup Functionality of the application

  Scenario: Create new User through NavBar
    Given User is on Landing Page
    And User Click on SignUp button in NavBar
    And User enter the Following Details
    And User click Register Button
    Then User should be navigated to Questionnaire Page
```

Test Runner

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/java/com/ksupwlt/stepcounttracker/features"},
        glue = "com.ksupwlt.stepcounttracker.steps"
       )
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    @Override
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

Hooks:

```
public class Hooks {
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Value("${app.url}")
    private String appUrl;

    @Before
    public void InitializeTest(Scenario scenario){
        webDriver.get(appUrl);
        webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        utility.message = scenario;
    }

    @After
    public void TearDownTest(Scenario scenario) throws IOException {
        if(scenario.isFailed()){
            System.out.println("failed");
        }
```

Utility:

```
public class utility {

    @Autowired
    private static WebDriver webDriver;

    public static Scenario message;

    public static String takeScreenShotAfterEveryScenario(WebDriver webDriver) throws IOException {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy h-m-s");
        Date date = new Date();
        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)webDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String destination =System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\report\\"+dateFormat.format(date)+".png";
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(destination));
        return destination;
```

scenario step where I want to display the screenshot in cucumber output

```
 @Then("User should be navigated to Questionnaire Page")
    public void userShouldBeNavigatedToQuestionnairePage() throws IOException {
        Assert.assertTrue(questionnairePage.qusTitle.isDisplayed());
        utility.takeScreenShotAfterEveryScenario(webDriver);
        String destiantion = utility.takeScreenShotAfterEveryScenario(webDriver);
        System.out.println("destination = "+destiantion);
    }
```

pom.xml:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ksu</groupId>
    <artifactId>weightLossTracker</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>weightLossTracker</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <selenium.version>4.7.0</selenium.version>
        <testng.version>7.7.1</testng.version>
        <seleniumhttp.version>4.5.0</seleniumhttp.version>
        <cucumberspring.version>7.11.1</cucumberspring.version>
        <groshopper.version>2.10.0</groshopper.version>
        <extentReport.version>5.0.9</extentReport.version>
        <commonio.version>2.11.0</commonio.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-http-jdk-client</artifactId>
            <version>${seleniumhttp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumberspring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumberspring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumberspring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/tech.grasshopper/extent-pdf-report -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extent-pdf-report</artifactId>
            <version>${groshopper.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.aventstack/extentreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
            <version>${extentReport.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commonio.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.8</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>com.ea.SpringBasic.SpringTestNGTest</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I added the extent report dependency not sure this is the correct one.